# Cancel NSURLConnection Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, connection, nsmutableurlrequest

I have a tableviewapplication, wich when the user select one view it needs to parse some XML to display information.But sometimes the XML is not finished downloading and the user can press the button to select the other view,generating a crash.I think i need to cancel the connection or something to dont cause any conflitct with the new connection,but i dont know exactly how,it suppose to be in ViewWillDisappear correct?
Heres how i start the connection on ViewDidAppear:

```
NSMutableURLRequest * req = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://Adress"]
                                                        cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:20.0f];

conn = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:req delegate:self];

[UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;

if(conn)
{
    receivedData = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];
    [DSBezelActivityView newActivityViewForView:self.view withLabel:@"Loading..."];
}


- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

    if(conn) [conn cancel];
}
```

Comment: the problem cannot be traced from the code you have shared. you should provide tableview's delegate methods along

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call NSURLConnection's cancel method and it will prevent your connections delegate from being called with any more data. You could do this in viewWillDisappear if that's when it makes sense given how your app works.

Comment: But to cancel NSURLConnection i have to declare it in .h file correct?

Comment: Yes, you will have to keep a reference around if you want to later cancel it

Comment: I edited the post to the code im using now,i keep a reference now,but how i check if the connection is receiving data to cancel it,of o try to cancel it,and the connection is not occurring,gets me a crash.

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely you can `cancel NSURLConnection`.

But you should be careful in cancelling it too.

If you decide to `cancel` it in `viewWillDisappear`,

then

You should not do,

```
autorelease
```

and also you should not,

`release` it anywhere.

**Here below the brief explaination:**

Do `cancel` your `NSURLConnection` delegate in `viewWillDisappear`

```
[nsurlconnection cancel];
```

and also you should `release` it here not anywhere,

```
[nsurlconnection release];
```

If you release the `connection` in somewhere like after your `xml response` received then,

It will call the `viewWillDisappear` method anyway,

here you are cancelling it , then it will lead your app to crash.

> "deallocated objects will not be cancelled"

.

And also another situation will occurs while cancelling,

If user comes and immediately navigates other view first time, your `nsurlconnection` will be cancelled in `viewWillDisappear` method.

Again the user comes to the `view` and escapes immediately before your `nsurlconnection` initialized or allocated, also your app will be crashed because,

> "deallocated objects will not be cancelled".

So, check your `connection != nil` before you `cancel` it 
and also don't forgot to do

```
nsurlconnection = nil;
```

in the same time.

So that you can avoid the immediate calls [nsurlconnection cancel] crashes.

SO Finally , in your `viewWillDisappear` method you have to do is,

> 1. Need to check nsurlconnection != nil
> 2. Need to cancel it
> 3. Need to allocate null to your nsurlconnection
> 4. Need to release it in the same method.

**Sample code will be like the following,**

```
- (void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{

if (nsurlconnection != nil)
{
[nsurlconnection cancel];
[nsurlconnection release];
nsurlconnection = nil;
}
```

}

Hope it's helpful... Happy coding ...